# How to make an applet not float in html

Tags: html, internet-explorer, applet, z-index

I want the applet not floating in html.

When I open a jQuery modal window, the window is behind the applet component.

Now, how can I make the applet same layer as regular html text, inputs, buttons etc...so that the jQuery modal window is on top of the applet?

I already tried: `z-index: -1` and `z-index: -99999` but it doesn't work.

Browser use: IE7 and IE9

Comment: What kind of applet are you talking about? Are you having issues with a Flash component floating above the other content in your page?

Comment: Hi, I'm talking about java applet

Comment: I'm not familiar with Internet Explorer, but in some older browsers I used, Java applets drew directly into the browser window. This means that the browser cannot reliably draw *anything* on top of the applet. If this is the case here then you must either give up putting anything on top, draw your overlay inside the applet itself, or avoid using Java — I recommend that last option, as JavaScript has made immense advances.

Comment: hi Kevin, as of now we cannot use pure javascript because ie9 does not support drag-n-drop file upload support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use an iframe to float content above an applet.

Im in the same boat, where we have to use a java applet to communicate with a mainframe system.  We need to display dynamic content in a popover and the only way I have been able to accomplish that is with using an iframe.

**CSS:**

```
.popover {

    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    left: 10px;
    /*z-index: 999;*/

    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(140, 140, 140, .9);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<iframe class="popover"></iframe>
```

**Note:** border-radius and box-shadow will not work well in Firefox or chrome, when floated over the java applet.  Transparency is also an issue, however Chrome seems to handle all three better than Firefox.

Comment: I also encounter this issue on chrome but in firefox the applet is behind the jQuery modal window and it works properly.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: the firefox im using is 16.0.1

Comment: Strange, I just updated to 16.0.1 and still see the same results.  That being said, I'm using an iframe element specifically, and not a jQuery modal window.

Comment: i mean it work perfectly on firefox but not in chrome(latest) and ie7, ie 9.